# Is there a library which can export my Django models to UML?

Tags: django, django-models, uml

I'd like to export my models to a UML diagram. Is there currently a library which I could use within a Buildout project to export my models to a UML diagram to help review the relationships between objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's actually one in the django-extensions, given you are using *nix. pygraphviz is required which I don't believe has a windows counterpart.

http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/29/django-uml/